# Can you weak link(optional link) a static library in C++ like Objc could?

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, objective-c++, weak-linking

I am developing a static library **A** with a mix of Objective C and C++ in Xcode, I run into the need to "weak link" another static library and Let's call it **B**. **A** calls some methods defined in **B**. The idea is that if **B** is not linked/provided, **A** will not throw any undefined symbols error.
I know that in Objective C you can do that and in code I can rely on run time methods such as NSClassFromString or [someObject Class] to check if a certain function is present/available from another static library, but I don't know if I can achieve that in one of my .cpp source file. Please advise and thank you!

I created a very simple sample project for illustration purpose:

Library **A**:

Core_ObjC.h, this is the header that will be exposed

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Core_Objc : NSObject

-(int) calculate;

@end
```

Core_ObjC.mm

```
#import "Core_ObjC.h"
#include "Core_CPP.h"

@implementation Core_Objc

-(int) calculate{
    return calculate_Core();//Call into cpp here
}

@end
```

Core_CPP.cpp

```
#include "Core_CPP.h"
#include "NonCore_CPP.h"

int calculate_Core(){
    return calculate_NonCore();//Call into another cpp here but it's defined in Library B
}
```

Library **B**:

NonCore_CPP.cpp

```
#include "NonCore_CPP.h"

int calculate_NonCore(){
    return 100;
}
```

If I link both libraries in a sample app, the app will compile fine. However, when I link only A from the sample app, I will encounter error like:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "calculate_NonCore()", referenced from:
      calculate_Core() in CoreFramework(Core_CPP.o)
```

The error does make sense to me because **B** will have the missing definition, but I am just looking for a solution that the compilation won't complain when there is only **A**.

Comment: @OlSen I added more info, thanks.

Comment: @OlSen, you are right, I am looking for a way in C++ to check if a function is available from another library.

Answer (score 0):

So, weak linking works at the C function level as well. For [details, see Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html) but basically, the symbol needs to be declared using `__attribute__((weak_import))`, as follows

```
extern int MyFunction() __attribute__((weak_import));
extern int MyVariable __attribute__((weak_import));
```

and then you can check if its address is zero to check if it was found during link time, using e.g. `if (MyFunction != NULL)` or `if (&MyVariable != NULL)`.

Your title mentions static libraries. Note that static libraries are just collections of object files, so you either link the library or you don't; there's no weak linking a static library, because by definition, it's present at build time. Or not. If you want runtime behaviour, use a dynamic library. (dylib)

The above should actually cover the example you have given: you'll just need to provide alternative code for when `calculate_NonCore` is unavailable, as you can't call it without crashing the program. (Makes sense, it's missing)

You mention C++ too, although your code doesn't make any obvious use of it. C++ makes this a little more complicated because of its mangled names; additionally, classes themselves don't have any linkage, so you can't test for presence of a class. The compiler seems to allow applying the `weak_import` attribute to member functions, static member variables, etc. but I'm not sure to what extent the `NULL` checks will work. Free functions should certainly not be an issue - treat them like C functions - and I'd guess that static members are probably a good candidate because you can easily take their address.

I'd probably try to avoid calling into any code that makes use of any part of a class that might not be there, and set things up such that you can simply check for the presence of a "canary" static member variable or function, which, if present, you can conclude that the whole class is present.